# Why "echo <<EOF" not working as expected

Tags: bash

I am trying to understand the bash's here document feature. Below code works as expected and returns "abc" to terminal. If I replace the program `cat` by `echo` I do not see any output. Why I am not able to pass here document to echo ? Is it becuase it is a bash builtin ?
`cat <<EOF
 abc
 EOF`

"abc" is output to the terminal as expected.

No output for below comamnd though-

```
echo <<EOF
abc
EOF
```

Comment: `<<EOF` puts content on stdin. `echo` doesn't read from stdin.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/600253/why-is-xargs-necessary/600273#600273) about the difference between stdin and arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want:

```
cat <<EOF
abc
EOF
```

Otherwise, what you're doing is just running `echo` with its stdin connected to a temporary file having `abc` in it. Since `echo` doesn't read stdin, it never finds out if there's contents waiting to be read from there or not.

Comment: Marked community wiki to avoid harvesting rep from a known dupe